# How do I pass multiple symbol arguments to #options_for_select (including :include_blank, :class, and :required)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following line in my Rails application (version 4.1):

```
= f.select :method, options_for_select(ApplicationHelper::VERBS, 'GET'), {}, required: true, class: 'form-control'
```

Where `ApplicationHelper::VERBS` is just an Array of different HTTP verbs. I want the GET verb to be the default option (thus the `...VERBS, 'GET')`. I want the field to be required (thus the `required: true`). I want it to have a CSS class of `form-control`. The above line does all these.

I also don't want to have an empty option in the dropdown. I know I have to use `include_blank: false` but when I put it at the end of that line, it doesn't work (meaning the blank space is still there):

```
= f.select :method, options_for_select(ApplicationHelper::VERBS, 'GET'), {}, required: true, class: 'form-control', include_blank: false
```

How, with all the options I want, do I get rid of that empty space in my dropdown?

Comment: Nothing I tried works in rails 4.0.0.  Sorry.  The *option* `include_blank: false` seems inoperative.  As far as I can tell, f.select should work like this: `f.select(
      :color,
      options_for_select(['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'], selected="GET"),
      options={'include_blank' => false},
      html_options={class: 'form-control', required: true},
`   And putting :include_blank in the html_options doesn't work either.

Comment: Yeah @7stud, would you say this is a Rails bug? I'll report it if no one finds a way of doing this.